# pass this and second parameter to callback function

Tags: javascript, foreach

I have a JSCS rule that identifies functions within for loops. I'm wanting to adhere to the rule vs turn off the warning. This is the code in the JSCS error state.

```
let sum = 0;
for (var key in denomGroup) {
    denomGroup[key].forEach(function (denom) {
        sum = addToSum(sum, denom)
    });
}
return sum;
```

I've tried this below and the `addToSum` function gets the object, but I can't figure out how to pass in the sum and have it iterate and continue to add other values

```
for (var key in denomGroup) {
    denomGroup[key].forEach(addToSum);
} 

function addToSum(denom, sum) { //denom has object, sum is empty
    return sum += denom.sum;
}
```

I've also tried

```
for (var key in denomGroup) {
    denomGroup[key].forEach(addToSum(sum));
} 

function addToSum(sum, denom) { //sum has 0, denom is empty
    return sum += denom.sum;
}
```

How can I correctly call an outside function with the intent of the first code block? I need to avoid just placing `sum` as a global variable.

Comment: How about using `Array.reduce()` and not having to worry about any of this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass the `sum` to the function, simply declare the function within the same scope as you declare `sum`:

```js
let sum = 0;
let denomGroup = {
  a: [1,2,3],
  b: [4,5,6]
};

function addToSum(denom) {
  return sum += denom;
}

for (var key in denomGroup) {
  denomGroup[key].forEach(addToSum);
}

console.log(sum);
```

EDIT: as @ScottMarcus points out, the `sum` variable doesn't need to be global, just in the same (or a higher) scope as the function definition. You could, for example, encapsulate the whole thing as so:

```js
function countDenoms(denomGroup) {
  let sum = 0;

  function addToSum(denom) {
    sum += denom;
  }

  for (var key in denomGroup) {
    denomGroup[key].forEach(addToSum);
  }

  return sum
}

console.log(countDenoms({
  a: [1, 2, 3],
  b: [4, 5, 6]
}));
```

Comment: I was hoping to not have `sum` be a global variable if possible

Comment: @JonHarding It doesn't have to be global, it can just be in a higher scope.

Comment: @ScottMarcus is exactly correct; I've updated my answer to include that detail

Comment: Yes, your edit is what I ended up implementing. It's been a long day... must've been brain farting